# Training a forward dynamics model of a physical system using neural network

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to predict the forward dynamics of a physical system using neural networks. The equation is
`f(X_t,A_t) = (X_{t+1} - X_t)/dt`  where `X` is the state vector composed of angular positions and angular velocities and `A_t` is the control input and `dt` the small increment in time `t`. I have 10k data points.

My code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler, QuantileTransformer
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

print(tf.__version__)

"""
Trying to find the increment in states, f_(theta), from the equation
x_{t+1} = x_t + dt * f_(theta)(x_t, a_t)
x: [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q1d, q2d, q3d, q4d, q5d, q6d, q7d]  # q : angular positions, qd: ang velocities
a: [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7]  # control input
"""
data = np.load('state_actions_10k.npy', allow_pickle=True)
X = np.hstack((data[:, :7], data[:, 7:14]))
U = data[:, 14:]
dX = np.diff(X, axis=0)  # state residual

dt = 1
scalarX = StandardScaler()  # MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))#StandardScaler()# RobustScaler()
scalarU = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scalardX = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))

scalarX.fit(X)
scalarU.fit(U)
scalardX.fit(dX)

normX = scalarX.transform(X)
normU = scalarU.transform(U)
normdX = scalardX.transform(dX)

inputs = np.hstack((normX, normU))
inputs = inputs[:-1]
outputs = normdX

n, test_frac, train_frac = len(X), 0.2, 0.7
val_frac = 1 - test_frac - train_frac

X_train = inputs[:int(n*train_frac)]
X_test = inputs[int(n*train_frac):int(n*(train_frac+test_frac))]
X_val = inputs[int(n*(train_frac+test_frac)):]

Y_train = outputs[:int(n*train_frac)]
Y_test = outputs[int(n*train_frac):int(n*(train_frac+test_frac))]
Y_val = outputs[int(n*(train_frac+test_frac)):]

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=(21,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(14),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

train = True
if train:
    history = model.fit(
        X_train,
        Y_train,
        batch_size=64,
        epochs=100,
        # We pass some validation for
        # monitoring validation loss and metrics
        # at the end of each epoch
        validation_data=(X_val, Y_val),
    )
    model.save_weights('save_weights/trained_weights')
else:
    model.load_weights('save_weights/trained_weights')

print("Evaluate on test data")
results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=128)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)

print("Generate predictions for 3 samples")
predictions = model.predict(X_test[:3])
print("predictions shape:", predictions.shape)
```

I see that the validation accuracy is 0.9 at the end which I think is quite low. The `state_actions.npy` and the saved networks weights are available [here](https://github.com/ashBabu/Machine-Learning/tree/master/data)

```
Epoch 100/100
1094/1094 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 9.5670e-05 - accuracy: 0.9777 - val_loss: 0.0014 - val_accuracy: 0.9055
Evaluate on test data
157/157 [==============================] - 0s 759us/step - loss: 2.5453e-04 - accuracy: 0.9586
test loss, test acc: [0.0002545334573369473, 0.9585979580879211]
```

Can someone suggest a method to improve the accuracy?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `microsoft-dynamics` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Dynamics are continuous, so this is a regression problem, not a classification one. Accuracy only makes sense in a classification setting.